# compareTo() function in Java

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

I have written the code below

```
import java.util.*;
class compare{
    public static void main(String []args){
        String s1="java";
        String s2="javaProgramming";
        System.out.println(s1.compareTo(s2));
    }
}
```

The output for this code is -11. Since there is no character for termination of string in java, which character in "java" is being compared with 'P' in "javaProgramming"?

Comment: If you are interested in the details, also consider that sensible comparison is language dependent, that is based on the Locale: Collator. That can decides an order like `o  < od < ö < oe < ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'P' character is not compared to anything in the first `String`.

It only compares the first 4 characters of the 2 Strings, which are equal to each other.

Then it returns the length of the first String minus the length of the second String.

```
public int compareTo(String anotherString) {
    int len1 = value.length;
    int len2 = anotherString.value.length;
    int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);
    char v1[] = value;
    char v2[] = anotherString.value;

    int k = 0;
    while (k < lim) {
        char c1 = v1[k];
        char c2 = v2[k];
        if (c1 != c2) {
            return c1 - c2;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return len1 - len2;
}
```

Since the second `String` is longer, and the first `String` is contained in the second, returning any negative value will do, since the shorter `String` should come first in lexicographical order.

Answer (score 4):

Let see what [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) say about it

> Compares two strings lexicographically. The comparison is based on the
>   Unicode value of each character in the strings. The character sequence
>   represented by this String object is compared lexicographically to the
>   character sequence represented by the argument string. The result is a
>   negative integer if this String object lexicographically precedes the
>   argument string. The result is a positive integer if this String
>   object lexicographically follows the argument string. The result is
>   zero if the strings are equal; compareTo returns 0 exactly when the
>   equals(Object) method would return true.
>
> This is the definition of lexicographic ordering. If two strings are
>   different, then either they have different characters at some index
>   that is a valid index for both strings, or their lengths are
>   different, or both. If they have different characters at one or more
>   index positions, let k be the smallest such index; then the string
>   whose character at position k has the smaller value, as determined by
>   using the < operator, lexicographically precedes the other string. In
>   this case, compareTo returns the difference of the two character
>   values at position k in the two string -- that is, the value:
>
> ```
>  this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)
> ```
>
> If there is no index position at which they differ, then the shorter
>   string lexicographically precedes the longer string. In this case,
>   compareTo returns the difference of the lengths of the strings -- that
>   is, the value:
>
> ```
>  this.length()-anotherString.length()
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in [the source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l1140), the comparison stops when the minimum of the lengths of each string is reached. If all characters are equal through that point, then the difference in lengths is returned.